# How can I listen to network change event in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I was just trying to figure out how can I add the network change event in windows so that I can run the custom logic when the network changes. For example, when my windows device gets connected to a wifi network I want to send the post request to the desired url.

The idea is my ISP has implemented some sort of the captive portal to disallow the user to access the internet who doesn't have the login credentials so I want to write the function that can automatically send the post request to the captive portal and log me in

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/NetworkListManager  - check out ListenToNetworkConnectivityChangesSample